# Set subplot height/width

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to create a window with a set of subplots in it. The subplots must be of different height:

- 1st -- 50%
- 2nd and 3rd -- 25% each

I was playing with `row`, `col`, `rowspan`, and `colspan` arguments but with no luck.
So, the questions are: how to control the size (height, width) of a subplot (at creation or/and after it's created)?

[Current heights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb3Z6.png)

[Heights needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts5Mw.png)

My current code is below:

```
import PyQt5
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
from random import randint as ri

def BarChart(x):
    global layout
    barPlot = layout.addPlot(row=0, col=0, rowspan=2, colspan=1)
    barPlot.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.5)
    barPlot.plot(x)
    ax = barPlot.getAxis('bottom')
    ax.setStyle(showValues=False)
    return barPlot

def IndChart(x, barPlot):
    global layout
    indPlot = layout.addPlot(row=2, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
    indPlot.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.5)
    indPlot.plot(x)
    indPlot.setXLink(barPlot)
    ax = indPlot.getAxis('bottom')
    ax.setStyle(showValues=False)
    return indPlot

def IndChart2(x, barPlot):
    global layout
    indPlot = layout.addPlot(row=3, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
    indPlot.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.5)
    indPlot.plot(x)
    indPlot.setXLink(barPlot)
    return indPlot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    view = pg.GraphicsView()
    layout = pg.GraphicsLayout()
    layout.layout.setSpacing(0)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    view.setCentralItem(layout)
    view.show()
    x = [0] + [ri(0, 100) for i in range(100)] + [100]
    barPlot = BarChart(x)
    indPlot = IndChart(x, barPlot)
    indPlot2 = IndChart2(x, barPlot)
    x = [0] + [ri(0, 100) for i in range(100)] + [100]
    barPlot.plot(x, pen=(255, 0, 0))
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some solution (maybe not the best but, at least, it is something). `layout`'s `height` property may be used together with `setFixedHeight` property of a plot.

Example of usage:

`indPlot.setFixedHeight(layout.height() * 0.25)`